# Sanitizing of electronic items during COVID

Tags: pcb, cleaning

I am considering to purchase a new desktop PC ( components, will assemble myself ). I am worried about the inability to use everyday sanitizers to clean, for example, a motherboard.

Is there any guidance on how to sanitize and decontaminate an electronic item, like a motherboard, CPU, GPU, PSU, RAM, HDD? What can I do to eliminate the risk of microbes on the surface? Any solvents? Just let it dry in the sun? Can I clean it with an antiseptic liquid (water solution) and let it dry off? Or just delay the purchase until everything improves?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!!

Comment: By the time it ships to the us and then travels through the mail to you the internals of each box will be non-infectious. Disinfecting it is unnecessary and unhelpful.

Comment: This is not true, it can persist on objects for days. Disinfecting electronics may not be necessary but it's still prudent.

Comment: The average shipping and delivery time here is around 2-4 days approx. And I doubt if that is long enough.

Comment: @user148898 It takes more than 2-4 days for a product to reach the consumer. Manufacturing dates are usually weeks or months earlier, or even longer if the product was sent by container ship.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about biology not electronics.  Why would you clean a motherboard anyway, you're not going to touch your face to it.  Build up the system then wash your hands same as when you handle any item coming from others such as mail, just-purchased groceries, etc.  Worry about cleaning the *keyboard* and *mouse*.

Comment: The components are in the box for weeks or months and are not even handled for most of the manufacturing and packaging process (and if they are handled, gloves are likely), if at all. If you want to be worried, be worried about the exterior packaging.

Comment: Most likely, everything inside the packaging has been sitting in a warehouse for a couple of months.

Answer (score 4):

According to this source, virus can live 2-3 days on plastic and 1 day on cardboard. So, after you remove packet, you wash your hands. Then it will be ok.
https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/transmission/

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that everything inside the packages is okay. I open the packages and discard or set aside the packaging, wash my hands and that's it. I only clean the outside of packages if they are going into the freezer or fridge as-is. I use 5:1 dilute spray bleach for that, because it's cheaper than alcohol, even though it might damage some things.

The bits and pieces that were packed in China or Vietnam were probably okay when they left, and have been in the box for long enough. The courier, order pickers and so on might have handled it minutes or hours earlier.

If you are still worried, you can spray many things with 99% isopropanol without much risk if  you are still worried. Do not use drug store rubbing alcohol, it has added stuff that leaves a residue. There's no need to clean anything that's going to end up inside the computer case, in my opinion. Just things you might touch again in the next few days (unless they are being kept colder than room temperature).

Comment: Turns out 70% alcohol is better than 90+% at killing viruses, Covid-19 specifically. https://www.contecinc.com/articles/how-to-clean-covid-19/

Comment: @Aaron Yeah. But there's no way I'd use 70% on electronics. Water plus other unwanted ingredients are present. If CP (USP/NF) grade isopropanol isn't perfect, you still need to accept what it does achieve, I think. Sometimes, you have to balance trade-offs when you do something.

Comment: @jonk If it's good quality 70% alcohol the water is supposed to be pure as well. (not those green colored ones).  **Water does not hurt electronics** when there is no power applied. Manufactures wash PCAs after soldering all the time with *water*.  Yes they claim it's de-ionized, but it's recycled a bunch usually, so isn't pure either.

Comment: @Aaron I wouldn't place the highly polar water on electronics. It attracts things (and concentrates oxygen from air) and has a high surface tension. The isoprop will evaporate first and leave 100% water on the surface. Not a happy circumstance. So I can't agree. The other "pretty good" option that Spehro didn't mention is to heat the boards up to about \$150\:^\circ\text{F}\$ and hold it there for about 5 minutes or so. (A home dryer can achieve this, but you must arrange not to tumble the parts.) That most certainly will kill the virus (and bacteria.) But I would NOT put water on electronics.

Comment: @jonk It's weird that they make these: https://www.pcbunlimited.com/products/incle-3600-inline-conveyorized-aqueous-cleaner No alcohol required.

Comment: @Aaron If you can afford one of those, I'd say go for it. ;) I think all of us who have tried 70% at home know from personal experience the troubles that can result. We've learned, early, to switch to 99%. I don't know of a single hobbyist who hasn't learned that lesson. I'm surprised you haven't.

Comment: That's a lot of valuable information. Thanks a lot! I am receiving suggestions from friends that I could use a Dettol or Savlon soaked cloth (no water) to wipe the items. Can I do that? Will it corrode and damage my parts? As for the residue, the suggestion I got was to clean it with 70 or 99 IPA solution. So sort of like a two pass cleaning routine.

Comment: As I said, I wouldn’t touch the PCBs themselves, just button them inside. If you start wiping things with whatever you need to worry about ESD damage and physical damage.

Comment: The primary reason for my worry is that temperatures are very often below 20° C here. It's monsoon, humidity is high and sunshine is low. I have a couple of hard disks that I require swapping around, meaning that I will have to touch the parts couple of times in a week. I could just let everything dry out in the open for 10-15 days and then assemble the parts, but given the humidity, I am worried about precipitation and water collection. Extra cables and manuals and gear that comes with the parts is an extra thing to clean and worry about, Not sure what the best option for me right now is.

Answer (score 0):

With no power applied, you can use 70% alcohol. Brush it on, or wipe it down, and let it evaporate to dry.  This will not harm the electronics or circuit boards.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the help. Can I also use it on the CPU (the bottom side with the pins)?

Comment: Sure. But now you are risking ESD damage and bent pins. I would focus only on the things that a person would normally touch. There is no point in removing a CPU from antistatic container to sanitize it, it's already clean, either because of shipping time, or it never got contaminated in the first place.  If said CPU/parts are inside a computer already, then you have nothing to worry about.